# How can I access via SSH a Jupyter notebook that is running in a Docker container?

Tags: docker, ssh, jupyter-notebook, port, jupyter

I have a GPU machine, a server and a client. As the GPU machine is behind security infrastructure, I have it maintain a reverse-SSH connection to the server so that the client can access the GPU machine from the server:

```
ssh -R 19507:localhost:22 www.example.org
```

Then, the client can access the GPU machine:

```
ssh -L 19508:localhost:19508 user@www.example.org -t ssh -L 19508:localhost:19508 user@localhost -p 19507
```

A Jupyter notebook can be set running on the GPU machine:

```
jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=19508
```

And then it is accessible remotely by the client via the URL localhost:19508.

Now, instead of running Jupyter on the GPU machine just using a system installation, I'd like to run it from a Docker container. When I run that same Jupyter command from within the container, I encounter the following message:

```
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

How can this be addressed? How can the Jupyter notebook within the container broadcast to the 19508 port such that it is remotely accessible via SSH?

The way I am launching the Docker container is something like the following:

```
docker run -u 'root' -v /home/repositories:/repositories -p 19508:19508 --ip 0.0.0.0 --gpus all -it --rm tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu
```

Comment: Have you verified already that you can see the GPU and execute something meaningful on it without the jupyter, but from within the container?

Comment: Yes, that all seems fine. The issue is getting Jupyter within the container connected to the SSH port.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were gong to having a slightly different problem than the one you actually are.